# Django - concatenate form fields before validation

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, concatenation

There is a Person model in `models.py`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    tel = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, default='')
    ...
```

Where `phone` is of type [PhoneNumberField](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field/blob/master/phonenumber_field/modelfields.py#L39)
Now, in my forms I have something like this:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Some code...
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = [..., 'phone',...]

        phoneprefix = ChoiceField(choices=phone_prefixes)
```

Where `phone_prefixes` is list that maps, well, phone prefixes so user can choose from dropdown list phone code for his desired country, for example `+44` for UK.

What I want to achieve is to make Django concatenate value of `phoneprefix` to `phone` in form, and *then* run any validation to check if phone number is possible/valid.
[django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field/) library has some nice functions for validation, but I want them to be run on `+44 1632 960741`, not just `1632 960741`.
How can I do that?

Comment: You may want to have a look at `forms.MultiValueField` ("aggregates the logic of multiple fields that together produce a single value")  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom validation by overwriting the form.clean method. This is the recommended way in the Django documentation. See here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean

Your code would become:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        # get the clean data 
        cleaned_data = super(PersonForm, self).clean()

        # get phone prefix value
        phoneprefix = cleaned_data.get("phoneprefix ")

        # get phone number value
        phone = cleaned_data.get("phone")

        # now we can perform the combined validation
        full_number = phoneprefix + phone 

        if not full_number .... :  # perform your validation
             raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid phone number")
```

Comment: Well, the problem is in this case `cleaned_data` does not have `phone`, because it is being treated as invalid by PhoneNumber.

Comment: Then do not use a phone field for "phone". Use a Charfield and write your own validation. Or overwrite the clean_phone function to prevent the validation error